# dependency injection PHP containers and construct injections

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I have a simple question.

```
class controller{

  $model;
  $view;
  $db;
  $array;

  public function __construct(Model $model, View $view, Database $db, Input $array){
    $this->model = $model;
    $this->view = $view;
    $this->db= $db;
    $this->array = $array;   
  }

  public function giveToModel{

    $this->model->someFunction($this->view, $this->db , $this->array);

  }

}
```

Now, im kind of new to programming so i have a few questions.In order to adhere to certine principles in coding like SOLID and so on, DI is a must. However i am slighty lost as to how to implement it in a MVC framework. I just need some pointers.

As to the code above. I am realy unsure as to the injection there. Is there a need to inject all of that through the constructor. or should i inject some of it (View $view, Database $db, Input $array) through the function "giveToModel".

And one more. Can i make two containers for example like this:

```
class controllerDepen {

  public function loadModel($name){
    return new $name.'Model';
  }

  public function postArray(){
    return new $postData; //object that gathers all the $_POST data into one array
  }

}
```

And another one to handle dependencies for the model and then pass those and use them to set dependencies.

My main problems are:

1. want i have too many dependencies at some point to pass normaly through the __construct
2. Decoupling the classes

I know there are DIC for things like this, however, i would really like to get a frim footing into this subject before using those.

As you can see, i might need some extra explanation regading this subject.

Comment: The general rule is that if a class instance won't work without a particular dependency then that dependency should be injected via constructor.  If a class instance can be used without a dependency but can use one to its benefit then it can be injected via constructor (with a =null default value) or via a setter method after construction.  In that case it's a judgement call which one is acceptable, with factors like "Is it okay for the dependant instance to be replaced with a different instance during the consuming class's life cycle?" helping to inform the decision)

Comment: ok, i get that. Only pass through the constructor what you must. Then to add to that question. if i work within the MVC framework, do i need to creat an instance of the view in the bootstrap class and then pass it to the model through the controller or creat it in the controller and send it to the model?

Comment: In this particular case I suspect the controller dictates which view is necessary?  If that's the case then it may be best to set up a factory in the DI container (Auryn supports this and I suspect most other DI frameworks too) that determines the specific controller and constructs it with the correct view.  The delegate() and prepare() features may both be relevant in this case. https://github.com/rdlowrey/auryn#instantiation-delegates

Comment: hmm. it goes bootstrap(explode $url call right controller)->controller->model->view. however if i am to adhere to the DI concept i have to provide the model with a instance of the view from the "outside". so do i create the view in the bootstrap and then send it to the controller and then to model or do i implement a container in the controller that "makes" the instance and then send it from there. that is what is confusing me